# convertRect:toView: function has different result in iOS 9 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have **sourceFrame** and **destinationFrame** which is calculated by the following code:

```
CGRect sourceFrame = [sourceView convertRect:sourceView.bounds toView:self.animationContainerView];
CGRect destinationFrame = [destinationView convertRect:destinationView.bounds toView:self.animationContainerView];
```

In iOS 9, the result is

```
sourceFrame = (origin = (x = 0, y = 386), size = (width = 375, height = 45))
destinationFrame = (origin = (x = 48, y = 28), size = (width = 319, height = 32))
```

While in iOS 10, the result is

```
sourceFrame = (origin = (x = 0, y = 386), size = (width = 375, height = 45))
destinationFrame = (origin = (x = -139.5, y = -281), size = (width = 319, height = 32))
```

destinationFrame's origin are totally different in iOS 9 and iOS 10.

I don't know why? I guess is that maybe in iOS 10, Apple changes the implementation for convertRect:toView that makes different results.

Anyone has idea why?

Comment: Where are you calling this code? Provide some context.

Comment: I call this code from a tap action. Basically there are 2 views (Source and Destination). I tap Source and then in tap action, I will call this code to calculate the sourceFrame and destinationFrame.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more to go on. Are the views from storyboards / XIBs / programmatically instantiated? Are you using auto-layout? Has the destination view already been displayed at this point or only initialised?